# Behavior of an imported module across multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, import, overwrite

I am familiar with the fact that all import statements in python are executed only once. If reloading is needed, it can be done manually. This has been summarised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437591/3896008) SO answer. However, I am unable to understand the behavior of the following import statements.

I have a `config.py` file with the following line:

```py
x = 2
```

Now, in a python script `script_1.py`, I have the following:

```py
import config
import script_2

config.x = 5
script_2.print_config() 

config = "foo"
script_2.print_config()
```

and the `script_2.py` goes like this:

```py
import config
def print_config():
    print (config)
    print (config.x)
```

Running `script_1.py` gives:

```
<module 'config' from '/Users/xx/config.py'>
5
<module 'config' from '/Users/xx/config.py'>
5
```

The `config.x=5` statement updates the value inside the function `script_2`'s function (`script_2.print_config()`). As explained in user: Fanchen Bao's comment, this behavior is as if config was a global variable.

But for the second call, `config` is a string; this time, it does not seem to update the value and `script_2.py` still sees it as a module. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's because when you import `script_2` in `script_1.py`, `script_2` and `script_1` are sharing `config` (you can think of `config` as a global variable). Any change made to `config` in `script_1` will be reflected in `script_2` as well.

Comment: @FanchenBao, thanks got it! but I have now updated the question to include one more case, in here, it doesn't treat the config like a global, since it still retains the config.x value

Comment: When you import `config` and `script_2` in `script_1`, both `config` in `script_1` and `config` in `script_2` point to the same object, i.e., the config module. That's why changes to `config.x` in `script_1` is also seen in `script_2`. However, these two `config` are not the same thing. They are two symbols of the same name, living in two namespaces, but happening to point to the same object. Thus, after you change `config` in `script_1` to point to a string,  this change does not affect `config` in `script_2`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment, yes, it clarifies all the concerns! @FanchenBao! Would you like to post your comment as an answer? I think this is non-trivial for beginners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `config` and `script_2` are imported in `script_1`, both `config` in `script_1` and `config` in `script_2` point to the same object: the `config` module. That's why changes to `config.x` in `script_1` is also seen in `script_2`. However, these two `config` are not the same thing. They are two symbols of the same name, living in different namespaces. It just so happens that they point to the same object. It is totally okay for one `config` to point to something else and that will not affect the other `config` at all. This is exactly what happens when the `config` in `script_1` is changed to point to a string. This change has no effect on `config` in `script_2`.